# Как остановить ответ бота?

Tags: node.js, discord

В дискорде создается кнопка, по нажатию в период с 08:00 до 16:59 выдается ответ, что в данный момент магазин работает, дополнительно ответ, что с 17:00 до 23:59 он не работает. Жмешь на кнопку и ответ верный в промежутках времени, но он бесконечно повторяется. Можно ли его как-то остановить? С другими кнопками, написанными так же проблем нет. Только при использовании node-cron.

```
const msgss = new ActionRowBuilder()
            .addComponents(
               new ButtonBuilder()
                  .setCustomId('Successs')
                  .setLabel('График работы')
                  .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Success),
            )

         await interaction.guild.channels.cache.get(`1095424849131678493`).send({ components: [msgss] }),

            collector.on('collect', async i => {
               if (i.customId === 'Successs') {
                  await i.guild.channels.cache.get(`1095424849131678493`).send({ content: '**В данный момент:**', });
                  cron.schedule('0-59 0-59 8-16 * * 1', () => {
                     i.guild.channels.cache.get(`1095424849131678493`).send({ embeds: [on] })
                  });
                  cron.schedule('0-59 0-59 17-23 * * 1', () => {
                     i.guild.channels.cache.get(`1095424849131678493`).send({ embeds: [off] })
                  });
               }
```